# Word count into multi dimension array on javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, nested

> javascript code to find count of strings in the multi dimension array of x,y and z directions

```
function wordCount(Array, string) {    
 let count = 0;    
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length ; i++) {    
       for (let j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++) {    
       if (array[i][j] === string)    
        count++;    
       }    
 }    
      return count;    
}    
let array = [["w","e","w","o"],    
             ["w","o","e","w"],    
             ["o","w","o","e"]];    
console.log(wordCount(array, 'woe'));
```

Comment: I am unable to find errors inside this javascript code... does any one assist me

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: I am able to count w or o or e, but cannot count 'woe'

Comment: I need to count 'woe' appearing in the array

Comment: You are searching a word in an index, means say if array[0][0]='w' so you are comparing it with "woe", what you can do is match one by one with string.first match "w" then "o" then "e" all should be there after one another.

Comment: can you help with the rewrite of code

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (let j = 0; j < array[0].length; j++)
```

seems wrong to me. i think you want to check `array[i].length` instead of `array[0].length`

Comment: `array` is undefined anyway. Also, he didn't implement the direction lookup either, apparently.

Comment: how do I make direction lookup